# Errors occurred wher using Chef-solo+vagran+AWS+ Mac OS X

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I intended to using **Vagrant**,**Chef-solo** to establish a **AWS** environment.But I got some errors that I can not solve.Anybody can help me?

**The steps I used:**

1. Install all necessary environment on Mac OS X: such as vagrant, vagrant plugin, virtual box, chef, chef plugin and so on.
2. Download vagrant configuration files:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ICTatRTI/ict-chef-repo
   ```
3. `Vagrantfile`

   ```
   # -*- mode: ruby -*-
   # vi: set ft=ruby :
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
     # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
     # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.
     #config.vm.box_url = "https://opscode-vm.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.2.0.box"
     #config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-1204"
     config.vm.box = "dummy"
     config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888
     config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3333
     config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"

     config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
     #config.vm.provider :aws do |aws|
       aws.access_key_id     = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQ'
       aws.secret_access_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       aws.keypair_name = "usr-aws-2013"
       aws.availability_zone = "us-west-2c"
       aws.instance_type = "t1.micro"
       aws.region = "us-west-2"
       aws.ami = "ami-0849a03f"
       aws.security_groups = ['quicklaunch-1']
       aws.tags = { 
         'Name' => 'tong',
         'Description' => 'vagrant test'
       } 
       override.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/usr-aws-2013.pem"
       override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
     end
     config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|

        chef.node_name = 'base' 
        chef.cookbooks_path = "./cookbooks"
        chef.roles_path = "./roles"
        chef.add_role "base"
        chef.add_role "ushahidi"
      end

   end
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   vagrant up --provider=aws
   ```
5. Got the following errors

   ```
   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'aws' provider...
   WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1
   [default] Warning! The AWS provider doesn't support any of the Vagrant
   high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`). They
   will be silently ignored.
   [default] Launching an instance with the following settings...
   [default]  -- Type: t1.micro
   [default]  -- AMI: ami-0849a03f
   [default]  -- Region: us-west-2
   [default]  -- Availability Zone: us-west-2c
   [default]  -- Keypair: usr-aws-2013
   [default]  -- Security Groups: ["quicklaunch-1"]
   [default]  -- Block Device Mapping: []
   [default]  -- Terminate On Shutdown: false
   An error occurred while executing multiple actions in parallel.
   Any errors that occurred are shown below.

   An unexpected error ocurred when executing the action on the
   'default' machine. Please report this as a bug:
    The image id '[ami-0849a03f]' does not exist
   ```

Comment: Looks obvious to me: there is no "ami-0849a03f" in provided region and zone or you may have no access to it.

Comment: Hi @DracoAter I'm create a instance in a AWS EC2 console and I ensure there are a instance looks like " 
i-bddcf889
t1.micro
us-west-2b
 running" And I change the Vagrantfile "aws.availability_zone = "us-west-2b"
    aws.instance_type = "t1.micro"
    aws.region = "us-west-2"
    aws.ami = "ami-bddcf889"" but it show same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instance** and **AMI** are **different things** and they have different numbers too. So if you have *i-bddcf889* you cannot reference it in your Vagrantfile as *ami-bddcf889*.

Instead you don't have to create/start instance manually - you must provide ami from which Vagrant will create instance itself. For example take the one you made instance manually from.

Comment: Hi ,Sorry for late reply but there seems have several time difference between us. You'r right and I'm exactly misunderstand it. But how can I get this ami-number and region correctly?I found a site that, can find the amis, but I really don't know how to use it,Is there any difference in bootstrap files between these AMIS? these[link]https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/ref=srh_navgno_search_box?searchTerms=ami+chef&search=[/link]

Comment: There should not be any differences, if the OS is still of same type (Linux, Windows, Mac)

Comment: In my AWS Console page,I found  "You do not own any Images matching your filter criteria.Use the filter controls above to view Images owned by Amazon and others." in the <b>AMIs</b> tags, Do I need to create/import the AMIs in it?Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Search for Images owned by Amazon and others - they are public

Comment: Thank you very much~ I GOT IT~ IT WORKS!